# Can i use TortoiseGIT And Eclipse EGit on same Repo?

Tags: git, egit, tortoisegit

If my repo is create by TortoiseGIT, and imported to Eclipse, should i use EGit to operate the repo?

I afraid the repo database will crash due to different client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Unlike some other version control systems, all git clients are using exact same git object store format, and in general it is perfectly safe to use them in parallel.

Comment: So may i know where is the EGit's git bin folder? I have download GIT Portable and i would like to set EGit and TortoiseGIT use same version library. thanks you.

Comment: git object store is located under git repository root under hidden directory named `.git` - this root folder is the one you should use

Comment: On TortoiseGIT settings dialog, i have to set the git.exe location, so how about the git.exe of eclipse EGit? thanks you.

Comment: EGit does not need to use git.exe - it has its own Java implementation of git protocol

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use different Git clients, I have used SourceTree, Git command line (inside CYGWIN) and EGit on the same project and have never had any issues.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine; both are just fronted clients to access the underlying Git repository.